# How to add a search term to searchindex.js in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

For instance, I want to show 2 results when user enters `scopes`, and I have 2 occurrences of this word in my docs, but in `searchindex.js` there's nothing and I got no results.

Can somebody explain how it works?
*(I get results for other searches, e.g. `api`.)*